# Помогите разобраться с .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

У меня вот такой:

```
RewriteEngine on

# catch errors
ErrorDocument 401   /index.php?bff=errors&errno=401
ErrorDocument 403   /index.php?bff=errors&errno=403
ErrorDocument 404   /index.php?bff=errors&errno=404
ErrorDocument 500   /index.php?bff=errors&errno=500
ErrorDocument 501   /index.php?bff=errors&errno=501
ErrorDocument 502   /index.php?bff=errors&errno=502
ErrorDocument 504   /index.php?bff=errors&errno=504

# directory index file
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes                                                    
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

# www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# send to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^okvartirka\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://okvartirka.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Есть страница с адресом `okvartirka.ru/search/` я хочу сделать её основной страничной то есть главной но чтобы в адресной строке не было /search/

Помогите правильно отредактировать `.htaccess` чтобы главной страничной была главная страница с `/search/`

Comment: Можно структуру вашего сайта? где `index.php`?  И куда идет линк для `/search`?

Comment: вот мой index.php https://vk.cc/6LYUQn

где основные объявления https://okvartirka.ru/search/

Comment: Просто вот вместо этого `DirectoryIndex index.php` напишите так `DirectoryIndex (путь к обработчику страницы search)`

Comment: выходит ошибка "Доступ к указанной странице запрещен"

Comment: Понятно у тебя же все через `index.php` проходит, лучше сделать `call` к модулю `search` а не с помощью `.htaccess`, еще можешь сделать просто редирект, но это плохой вариант

Comment: "лучше сделать call к модулю search" это как?
если сделать редирект search всё равно будет в адресной строке